# Dynamically assign object values to variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to assign the values of the below array of objects into defined variables which are initialized as empty strings.

What I have tried up until now:

```
const transaction = [{
    number: 10,
    value: "Ten"
  },
  {
    number: 20,
    value: "Twenty"
  },
];


let transactionOneValue, transactionTwoValue, transactionOneNumber, transactionTwoNumber = "";

if (transaction.length > 0) {
  transaction.forEach(item => {
      [transactionOneNumber, transactionTwoNumber].forEach(num => num = item.number);
      [transactionOneValue, transactionTwoValue].forEach(val => val = item.value);
    });
  }
```

Expected output:

```
   transactionOneValue = "Ten",
   transactionTwoValue = "Twenty",
   transactionOneNumber = 10,
   transactionTwoNumber = 20
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What is expected output? And you can not return an object, you can return an array. To start with.

Comment: does this work for you https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-mts0z?file=/index.js

Comment: `let transactionOneValue, transactionTwoValue, transactionOneNumber, transactionTwoNumber = "";` only initializes the last variable. I don't understand the task, but do you perhaps want `let [{ value: transactionOneValue }, { value: transactionTwoValue }] = transaction;`, and the related for the other?

Comment: @Aaron I don't understand, you just changed keys from first object? Your task and code is really unclear, please elaborate and edit your question with proper expected output

Comment: @ikiK added the expected output and removed the incorrect return in question.

Comment: " into defined variables which are initialized as empty strings." And then you post an object as wanted outcome, with keys and values. Those are not the same.

Comment: @Medi, I need to return the values in my initialized variables

Comment: @ikiK sorry for the confusion, fixed the expected output. It is not supposed to be an "object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const transaction = [{
    number: 10,
    value: "Ten"
},
{
    number: 20,
    value: "Twenty"
},
];


let transactions = [];

if (transaction.length > 0) {
    transaction.map((value, index, array) => {
        for(x of Object.values(value)) {
            transactions.push(x);
        }
    })
}

let transactionOneNumber = transactions[0], 
    transactionOneValue = transactions[1],
    transactionTwoNumber = transactions[2], 
    transactionTwoValue = transactions[3];

console.log(transactionOneNumber);
console.log(transactionOneValue);
console.log(transactionTwoNumber);
console.log(transactionTwoValue);
```

output:

```
10
"Ten"
20
"Twenty"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring seems to be simplest approach here, but I don't see how this would be useful. Creating separate variables for every item in a list isn't scalable.

```
let [
  {number: transactionOneNumber, value: transactionOneValue},
  {number: transactionTwoNumber, value: transactionTwoValue}
] = transaction
```